# How to swap image out on click?

Tags: javascript, html

Attempting to learn basic javascript functions and html coding.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script>
    var bigHeart = new Image();
    bigHeart.src = "vDay.jpg"

    function goBig() {
      document.heart.src = bigHeart.src


    }
  </script>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Big Heart</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header onClick="goBig()"><img id="heart" src="vDay2">
  </header>

</body>

</html>
```

Expect image to be swapped with second image when user clicks the header on webpage.

Comment: you don't need to create a new image to add a `src` and then set this `src` value to other image, you can assing it directly. But, what problem are you facing? What is your question exactly? Do you have some console errors?

Comment: The images are not swapping when clicked

Comment: To retrieve an element on the page by its `id`, you should be using `document.getElementById("heart")`, not `document.heart`.

Comment: Thank you, that fixed the issue. I was following along in a textbook for an example.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are trying to do

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Big Heart</title>
  <script>
    function goBig() {
      document.getElementById("heart").src = "new image path/url";
    }
  </script>  
</head>

<body>
  <header onClick="goBig()">
    <img id="heart" src="old image path/url">
  </header>
</body>
</html>
```